# How to change volume of stem files while playing using python

Tags: python, audio

I'm attempting to write a python project that plays multiple parts of a song at the same time.

For background information, a song is split into "stems", and then each stem is played simultaneously to recreate the full song. What I am trying to achieve is using potentiometers to control the volume of each stem, so that the user can mix songs differently. For a product relation, the StemPlayer from Kanye West is what I am trying to achieve.

I can change the volume of the overlayed song at the end, but what I want to do is change the volume of each stem using a potentiometer while the song is playing. Is this even possible using pyDub? Below is the code I have right now.

```py
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

vocals = AudioSegment.from_file("walkin_vocals.mp3")
drums = AudioSegment.from_file("walkin_drums.mp3")
bass = AudioSegment.from_file("walkin_bass.mp3")

vocalsDrums = vocals.overlay(drums) 
bassVocalsDrums = vocalsDrums.overlay(bass)

songQuiet = bassVocalsDrums - 20

play(songQuiet)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this question, I ended up using pyaudio instead of pydub.
With pyaudio, I was able to define a custom stream_callback function. Within this callback function, I multiply each stem by a modifier, then add each stem to one audio output.

```py
def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    global drumsMod, vocalsMod, bassMod, otherMod
    drums = drumsWF.readframes(frame_count)
    vocals = vocalsWF.readframes(frame_count)
    bass = bassWF.readframes(frame_count)
    other = otherWF.readframes(frame_count)
    decodedDrums = numpy.frombuffer(drums, numpy.int16)
    decodedVocals = numpy.frombuffer(vocals, numpy.int16)
    decodedBass = numpy.frombuffer(bass, numpy.int16)
    decodedOther = numpy.frombuffer(other, numpy.int16)
    
    newdata = (decodedDrums*drumsMod + decodedVocals*vocalsMod + decodedBass*bassMod + decodedOther*otherMod).astype(numpy.int16)
    return (newdata.tobytes(), pyaudio.paContinue)
```